# saving only compressed image to database

Tags: php, mysql, upload

I am trying to save the compressed image to database as well as to the folder. Now both the images are getting saved. Here is my code

To compress image i used this code referring [reduce image size while uploading using the following PHP code used to upload image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25800310/reduce-image-size-while-uploading-using-the-following-php-code-used-to-upload-im)

Here is my complete code

```
$k1 = mysqli_query($con, "select img_path from members where     mem_id='".$_SESSION['user_id']."'");
$k2 = mysqli_fetch_array($k1);
$dirname = "pics/".$_SESSION['user_id']."/"; 
$target = $dirname . basename( $_FILES['docs']['name']); 

function thumbnail( $img, $source, $dest, $maxw, $maxh ) {      
    $jpg = $source.$img;

if( $jpg ) {
    list( $width, $height  ) = getimagesize( $jpg ); //$type will return the type of the image
    $source = imagecreatefromjpeg( $jpg );

    if( $maxw >= $width && $maxh >= $height ) {
        $ratio = 1;
    }elseif( $width > $height ) {
        $ratio = $maxw / $width;
    }else {
        $ratio = $maxh / $height;
    }

    $thumb_width = round( $width * $ratio ); //get the smaller value from cal # floor()
    $thumb_height = round( $height * $ratio );

    $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor( $thumb_width, $thumb_height );

    imagecopyresampled( $thumb, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $thumb_width, $thumb_height, $width, $height );

    $path = $dest.$img."_thumb.jpg"; // I want to save _thumb.php image
    imagejpeg( $thumb, $path, 75 );
}
imagedestroy( $thumb );
imagedestroy( $source );

}

if( isset( $_FILES['docs'] ) ) {
$img = str_replace( " ","_",$_FILES['docs']['name'] );
move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['docs']['tmp_name'], $target );
$source = "pics/".$_SESSION['user_id']."/";
$dest = "pics/".$_SESSION['user_id']."/";
thumbnail( $img, $source, $dest, 480, 400 );
unlink($dirname."/".$k2['img_path']);   
}

$m1 = "UPDATE members SET fname = '".$fname."', lname = '".$lname."',  password='".$password_hash."',  img_path = '".$docs."'  WHERE mem_id='".$_SESSION['user_id']."'";

}
```

**UPDATED**

```
$k1 = mysqli_query($con, "select img_path from members where     mem_id='".$_SESSION['user_id']."'");
$k2 = mysqli_fetch_array($k1);
$dirname = "pics/".$_SESSION['user_id']."/"; 
$target = $dirname . basename( $_FILES['docs']['name']); 

function thumbnail( $img, $source, $dest, $maxw, $maxh, $file) {      
    $jpg = $source.$img;

if( $jpg ) {
   ///list( $width, $height  ) = getimagesize( $jpg ); //$type will return the type of the image
    //$source = imagecreatefromjpeg( $file ); //<---got rid of this.
    $source = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($file)); //<----Added this.
    if( $maxw >= $width && $maxh >= $height ) {
        $ratio = 1;
    }elseif( $width > $height ) {
        $ratio = $maxw / $width;
    }else {
        $ratio = $maxh / $height;
    }

    $thumb_width = round( $width * $ratio ); //get the smaller value from cal # floor()
    $thumb_height = round( $height * $ratio );

    //$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor( $thumb_width, $thumb_height );

    imagecopyresampled( $thumb, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $thumb_width, $thumb_height, $width, $height );

    $path = $dest.$img."_thumb.jpg"; // I want to save _thumb.php image
    imagejpeg( $thumb, $path, 75 );
}
imagedestroy( $thumb );
imagedestroy( $source );

}

if( isset( $_FILES['docs'] ) ) {
$img = str_replace( " ","_",$_FILES['docs']['name'] );
//move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['docs']['tmp_name'], $target );  <----This is saving the picture you don't want.  
$source = "pics/".$_SESSION['user_id']."/";
$dest = "pics/".$_SESSION['user_id']."/";
$file = $_FILES['docs']['tmp_name']; //<---- This is the file you are making the image with.
thumbnail( $img, $source, $dest, 480, 400, $file);  //<--Added $file to your function.
//unlink($dirname."/".$k2['img_path']);   
}

$m1 = "UPDATE members SET fname = '".$fname."', lname = '".$lname."',  password='".$password_hash."',  img_path = '".$docs."'  WHERE mem_id='".$_SESSION['user_id']."'";

}
```

Comment: You code is saving two files: 1.)Move uploaded file which has your original file name. 2.)imagejpeg with the thumb added to file name.  Are those the two that you are talking about?

Comment: Yes. for ex: my image is DSC_0169.JPG. And 2 images are getting uploaded as DSC_0169.JPG and DSC_0169.JPG_thumb.jpg. Here i want to upload only DSC_0169.JPG_thumb.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment.  Your code is saving two files.
1.) move_uploaded_file() is saving a picture.
2.) imagejpeg() is saving a picture with the "_thumb" added to it.

So I made some changes to your code. 
1.) Lets not move_uploaded_file.
2.) I changed your thumbnail function to pass the file and created your image object from it directly.

See comments in the code.

```
$k1 = mysqli_query($con, "select img_path from members where     mem_id='".$_SESSION['user_id']."'");
$k2 = mysqli_fetch_array($k1);
$dirname = "pics/".$_SESSION['user_id']."/"; 
$target = $dirname . basename( $_FILES['docs']['name']); 

function thumbnail( $img, $source, $dest, $maxw, $maxh, $file) {      
    $jpg = $source.$img;

if( $jpg ) {
    //list( $width, $height  ) = getimagesize( $jpg ); //$type will return the type of the image  //<--This won't work anymore. 

    //$source = imagecreatefromjpeg( $file ); //<---got rid of this.
    $source = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($file)); //<----Added this.

    $width   = imagesx($source); //<---Added this
    $height  = imagesy($source); //<---And this  

    if( $maxw >= $width && $maxh >= $height ) {
        $ratio = 1;
    }elseif( $width > $height ) {
        $ratio = $maxw / $width;
    }else {
        $ratio = $maxh / $height;
    }

    $thumb_width = round( $width * $ratio ); //get the smaller value from cal # floor()
    $thumb_height = round( $height * $ratio );

    $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor( $thumb_width, $thumb_height );

    imagecopyresampled( $thumb, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $thumb_width, $thumb_height, $width, $height );

    $path = $dest.$img."_thumb.jpg"; // I want to save _thumb.php image
    imagejpeg( $thumb, $path, 75 );
}
imagedestroy( $thumb );
imagedestroy( $source );

}

if( isset( $_FILES['docs'] ) ) {
$img = str_replace( " ","_",$_FILES['docs']['name'] );
//move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['docs']['tmp_name'], $target );  <----This is saving the picture you don't want.  
$source = "pics/".$_SESSION['user_id']."/";
$dest = "pics/".$_SESSION['user_id']."/";
$file = $_FILES['docs']['tmp_name']; //<---- This is the file you are making the image with.
thumbnail( $img, $source, $dest, 480, 400, $file);  //<--Added $file to your function.
unlink($dirname."/".$k2['img_path']);   
}

$docs = $dest.$img."_thumb.jpg"; <---Updated path to save to database.

$m1 = "UPDATE members SET fname = '".$fname."', lname = '".$lname."',  password='".$password_hash."',  img_path = '".$docs."'  WHERE mem_id='".$_SESSION['user_id']."'";

}
```

That should work.  Hope that helps.

Comment: getimagesize() is giving warning. File path is getting updated in database but in folder its not getting uploaded. `Warning: getimagesize(pics/PCD8Q5/IMG_20161031_123058.jpg): failed to open stream:.. my file path`, `Warning: imagecreatetruecolor(): Invalid image dimensions in .. file path `..

Comment: @meenal You don't need it anymore.  Comment it out.  You can use $fileInfo = image_type_to_mime_type(exif_imagetype($file)); to get the exif data from the image if you still need it.

Comment: if i comment out getimagesize(), what about `list( $width, $height  )` otherwise width and height will be undefined right?

Comment: @meenal I added the width and height under the createimagefromstring

Comment: I have updated the code, i think i am missing something. Sorry. Can you please check the updated code. In that i am getting undefined width and height

Comment: @meenal you are missing the height and width.. Check my code they are there under the imagecreatefromsting function

Comment: Yes, now only _thumb image is uploading to the folder but to database renamed file is not getting saved, as i am saving `$docs=($_FILES['docs']['name']);` <- this. What i should replace?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167799/discussion-between-joseph-j-and-meenal).

Comment: @meenal I updated my code.  Look above your update query.  I opened a chatroom.  Please join, it will be quicker.